# When I try to train tensorflow's object detection api I get CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

```
python model_main.py --model_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2
_pets.config
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x00000155CFDB5C80>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable.
WARNING:root:Variable [global_step] is not available in checkpoint
D:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\envs\Eneger\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py:100: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may
consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
2018-07-24 05:19:44.209751: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorF
low binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2018-07-24 05:19:45.534609: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:

name: GeForce GTX 1060 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.97GiB
2018-07-24 05:19:45.571588: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-24 05:19:53.604693: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with stren
gth 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-24 05:19:53.615439: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-07-24 05:19:53.622183: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-07-24 05:19:53.643331: I C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/re
plica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4730 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-07-24 05:20:58.481169: E C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_event.cc:49] Error polling for event status: failed to query e
vent: **CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION**
2018-07-24 05:20:58.511921: F C:\users\nwani\_bazel_nwani\mmtm6wb6\execroot\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_event_mgr.cc:208] Unexpected Event status: 1
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information like `tensorflow` version, `cuda`, `cudnn` version and the os name?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open Issue on tensorflow github since March:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17747

But seems that the error appears randomly, not all times, can you confirm that? The last answer is 10 days ago, so i think they're still working on it.
L-

Comment: I read abot a GTX 1080Ti that when overclocked randomly give the same error, yours is a very similar Graphic card, It can be the same issue?

Comment: It is not overclocked, and happens consistently

Comment: How about GPU driver dowgrade to previous version? (or upgrade if is not updated).

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that your versions of cuda and cudnn are the compatible ones for your tensorflow versions. For example cuda toolkit 9.0 and not cuda toolkit 9.1 or cudnn 7.0 and not 7.05.
After that I would update the drivers of the GPU form the Official Nvidia website.

Answer (score 0):

I would not only check that you have CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.0, but I would also make sure that the CuDNN version you selected and installed is the one providing enabled for CUDA 9.0 (there are versions of CuDNN for CUDA 8.0, 9.0 and 9.1).

Comment: I am using cudo 9.0 and cudnn 7.0 with the correct cuda enabled. I should say that I can run some neural networks on the GPU without issue, it is the object detection network specifically that is failing as far as I can tell. However it succeeds on the CPU